# Customize syntax theme in ATOM

Tags: themes, atom-editor

I would like to modify a little bit the syntax theme of ATOM (an IDE). 
Usually I program in C++. I would like to change the "const" qualifier.

Do you know under which name goes the const qualifier of C++ in the "file.less"? Or, this would be even a better solution for me, where I can find a tutorial on about this files?

I don't know how to explain my situation, I try with an example. Suppose that I have this code

```
.syntax--comment {
color: #26afff;
font-style: italic;
}

.syntax--string {
color: #D14;
}
```

I know that "syntax--comment" refers to the comment but I don't know to what refers "syntax--string".